# Kernel Panic, unable to mount root

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, mount

I have recently dual booted to ubuntu 13.10 with windows 8. I have windows 8 before having ubuntu, I had to do a boot-repair so I can choose which to load, it all went fine, no problem.

But then again I decided to upgrade to windows 8.1, I thought I can just install it, then just use a live usb, to do a boot-repair again, but it gave me this error

```
 Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root (0,0)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to boot the Live USB or have you done a boot repair and are now trying to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: i am still at trying to boot the live usb,

Comment: Try checking the media (press a key when the USB first starts up and shows the logo at the bottom for the menu which will allow you to do this).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Dont know much of the basics but I found that the iso-file I used for making my bootable usb was corrupt.

Try changing the iso file.

Hope that helps.